# How do I chat in Draw Something?

Tags: draw-something

My opponent and I have been playing for a couple of years. He/she chats, but I can't seem to find out how to respond. How do I chat?

Comment: Do you talk about the small text message between each guess ?

Comment: yes, between drawings/guesses.

Answer (score 1):

If you fail or manage to guess, on the end screen you have a small text box at the bottom of the screen where you can write text.

Comment: Wow! You have to move really really fast!

Comment: @Bacardigyrl yes, It took me some time to realise too =p